# No response from request api(longer than 30min) while using SimpleHttpOperator

Tags: airflow

**Apache Airflow version**

2.1.2

**Operating System**

CentOS Linux 7

**Deployment**

Docker-Compose

**What happened:**

I'm using SimpleHttpOperator to request an api which get reponse longer than 30min often, but task is still in running state even api has already returned a response.

**What I'm expected to happen:**

I expected that task using SimpleHttpOperator could switch state from running to success so that downstream task could get into the queue.

**How to reproduce:**

Creat a SimpleHttpOperator task, request an api that need at least 30 min or more to response. Trigger this task you could find even api has returned a response, the task is still in running state.

Comment: Same issue any solution ?